# is it possible to have eclipse compile its classes in another directory than buildr's?

Tags: java, eclipse, buildr

I'm using buildr 1.4.4 with eclipse.

I do generate my eclipse files with buildr eclipse and it works fine. 
But it seems to me that .class files are completely different when eclipse compiles and when buildr compiles (it's OK, I know eclipse uses its own compiler). It becomes a problem when I want to use the incremental build : I have a lot a compilation errors under buildr (when I change an API) and I have to make `buildr clean test` every time to make it pass.

My question is : is it possible to have eclipse compile its classes in another directory than buildr's ?

I don't want an eclipse hack, but a buildr way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure eclipse output folder: `Right click project > Build Path -> Configure Build path > Source` and set the default build path at the bottom.

Buildr, and similar tools like maven or ant, are meant to be autonomous build systems, used without IDEs. Their IDE integrations (in the light of this question) simply configure the IDEs to output their classes according to the build tool configuration. You can't tell buildr that you want any eclipse configuration - buildr is IDE-agnostic.

Comment: My question is clear : I don't want an eclipse hack, but a buildr way of doing it.

Comment: @Jean-Philippe Caruana buildr is meant to be used outside eclipse. So using eclipse own configurations is not exactly a "hack". See updated.